# Is it possible to replicate an SDE geodatabase including the archive tables?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, replication, archiving

I have a database in one location which I would like to replicate to another using one-way replication. In testing we haven't been able to replicate the archive tables, which is unfortunate because we need to keep these historical versions in both locations.

Is it possible to simply replicate the whole DEFAULT database (including archive tables).

If not, is there any way to work around this?

Comment: There are several different forms of replication. Which one are you using?

Comment: The goal is to use the built-in ESRI geodatabase (one-way) replication.

Comment: You've tested that and stated that it doesn't work. A database-level replication technique would work, as would a change detection update technique.

Comment: The issue we have is we're working with topological data, which ESRI documentation explicitly states may break if we were to go the route of RDMS replication. My hope is that I can find a solution using our currently preferred replication method (ESRI), rather than using a different method.

Comment: thinking out loud here, but would it be possible to go the distributed geodatabase route to get a second copy of your GDB?

Answer (score 1):

This may not fully meet your requirements, however I have just tested having Archiving enabled on both Parent and Child replicas using one-way replication.

Edits made on Parent and then replicated through to Child show up in both the feature class and the archive in the child database.

Child Replica Archive:
[image: Child Replica Archive]

Unfortunately if a feature is edited more than once before the replicas are synchronized, only the last edit makes it into the Child archive.  This can be overcome by running sync more often or after every edit, however that may not be practical.

Parent Replica Archive:
[image: Parent Replica Archive]

In my screenshots above I have created a feature and saved (first parent archive record), edited to add attributes (second parent archive record), then replicated to Child (first child archive record).  Then I have edited the feature again and saved (third parent archive record) and replicated (second child archive record)